# How do i convert seconds into days in C?

Tags: c

I'm a bit lost, how can I convert the output of `sys_inf.uptime` (seconds) into days?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int main(void) {
  
  struct sysinfo sys_inf; // for system information
  sysinfo(&sys_inf); // to get system information

  int days = sys_inf.uptime;
  float totalDays = days / 86400;

  printf("Latest reboot was : %.2ld seconds ago (%.2f)", sys_inf.uptime, totalDays);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you managed to solve the problem, please post an _answer_ rather than an edit to the question.

Comment: Uptime does not necessarily mean that the system was rebooted.

Comment: Change int to long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing integer division here:

```
int days = sys_inf.uptime;
float totalDays = days / 86400;
```

Add `.0` to make it a floating point division:

```
int days = sys_inf.uptime;
float totalDays = days / 86400.0;
```

Comment: the  .0 is exactly what i need thank you so much !